# Enviro+ Pi Zero

Tags: raspbian

I am having problems with installing the Enviro+ board. I have connected the board and run the install code, however when I reboot the system freezes on the 'Welcome to Raspberry Pi Desktop' screen. I have turned the device off at the mains and then restarted it, however when I try to gop into Enviro+ it seems to be inly partially installed (gas.py and noise.py).

Has anyone else had similar problems and if so how did you fix them?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried following the tutorial at https://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/sandyj/getting-started-with-enviro-plus

Comment: Hi, Yes I have followed all the instructions on that site. Once I get beyond running the code for examples it stops working, foe example when I input this code:  from smbus2 import SMBus
from bme280 import BME280

bus = SMBus(1)
bme280 = BME280(i2c_dev=bus) : It says that SMBus cant be found. It should have been installed initially :/

Comment: It appears that the problem I am having is related to the i2c installation. Im new to this so sorry for the poor articulation but when I try to import from smbus2 its says module not found. When I list modules in help() it states 'Warning, could not find Analog or Touch, Please check your i2c settings'.

Comment: python2 or python3? Have you installed smbus for both versions? `sudo apt install python{,3}-smbus`. It's also `import smbus` and it **IS** case sensitive.

Comment: python 2.7.16. I havent done that as I assumed that smbus would have been installed with the initial installation. I'll try now and update you

Comment: So that hasnt worked. There is no module called smbus2 so I cants import it. I'm not sure what is the going on as this is the code from pimoroni. I checked the i2c settings and it seems to be fine.

Comment: When I type help("modules") the same warning message about i2c settings comes up but I cant see anything on pimoroni about this

Comment: Post your question on https://forums.pimoroni.com/ where the folks who wrote that stuff can help you.

Comment: You can also have a look at the discussion on the Raspberry Pi forums [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=163281) about using the BME280 which point to a few libraries and pages from Adafruit. You should be able to use the same to get the BME280 working